# How to check if there is already an appointment booked for request date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a condition to check if start date and end date exist or not 
if exist display message error

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
{
        var status = false;

        using (CalendarDBEntities1 db = new CalendarDBEntities1())
        {
            if (e.EventID > 0)
            {
                // Update the event
                var v = db.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();

                if (v != null)
                {
                    v.EventTitle = e.EventTitle;
                    v.StartDate = e.StartDate;
                    v.EndDate = e.EndDate;
                    v.EventDescription = e.EventDescription;
                    v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                db.Events.Add(e);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }
}
```

Can someone help me? I want to add this condition :

```
var exist = db.Events.Where(a => a.StartDate >= e.StartDate && 
                            a => a.EndDate >= e.EndDate).FirstOrDefault();


function SaveEvent(data) {
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('rendez-vous added');
                    window.location.href = "/Home/Calendar";
                }
    });
}
```

This is code to get events in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        var selectedEvent = null;
        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();

        function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
            events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            eventID: v.EventID,
                            title: v.EventTitle,
                            description: v.EventDescription,
                            start: moment(v.StartDate),
                            end: v.End != null ? moment(v.EndDate) : null,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                    })
```

This is code to save events in jQuery :

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
            //Validation/
            if ($('#txtSubject').val().trim() == "") {
                alert('Subject required');
                return;
            }

            if ($('#txtStart').val().trim() == "") {
                alert('Start date required');
                return;
            }

            if ($('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') == false && $('#txtEnd').val().trim() == "") {
                alert('End date required');
                return;
            }
            else {
                var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
```

I want to write a function like this when start date exist or end date get error

```
if (startDate > endDate) {
    alert('Invalid end date');
    return;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're asking. Do you want to check on the front-end or back-end?

Comment: i want to check in back-end

Comment: can i check in jquery without make condition in controller ??because i have a database events relied with controller

Comment: @aksil what model are you supplying to the create event page?

Comment: You have two `success` functions in your AJAX call

Comment: @aksil also what's the purpose of the exist variable-- do you plan to update an event if it exists instead of creating it?

Comment: thank you i  add some code to unterstand my problem  i want when user add start date or end date exist in data base he get message error

Comment: I am using the Full Calender js plugin, so far so good. but i want to check if a selection between the start and end has events?

I just need a true or false returned. Basically i want to stop users from creating events if an even already exists on the date selection.